# SQL Oracle: how to sort patient transfer data

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I want you to help me writing this query about patient transfers in the units. As most of you know, the patient can be transferred from one unit to another unit and also can be transferred from bed to another bed in the same unit, but for this query I want **only the unit transfers and to have the first arrival and the last update for each transfer in each different unit** and to ignore any bed to bed transfers, here is an example:

```
PATIENT_ID  Start_Date   END_DATE   UNIT_NAME   BED_NUMBER
----------------------------------------------------------
1           01/01/2015   01/02/2015     A          1
1           01/02/2015   01/03/2015     A          2    
1           01/03/2015   01/03/2015     B          1
1           01/03/2015   01/04/2015     C          5
1           01/04/2015   01/06/2015     C          8
1           01/06/2015   01/07/2015     C          9
1           01/07/2015   01/08/2015     A          1
```

The output should be:

```
PATIENT_ID  Start_Date   END_DATE     UNIT_NAME
------------------------------------------------
1           01/01/2015   01/03/2015      A
1           01/03/2015   01/03/2015      B
1           01/03/2015   01/07/2015      C
1           01/07/2015   01/08/2015      A
```

**Please note that the patient transfers can be done multiple times within the same day.**

Comment: Can you please share whatever you have tried till now?

Comment: `please note that the patient transfers can be done multiple times within the same day, thanks.` - are you storing the time along with the date?

Comment: You should look up `GROUP BY` in oracle. This is the most basic `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: @ruudvan, it would be a simple `GROUP BY` if not for the fact that a patient could be moved from unit A to unit B to unit C and then back to unit A (per the data in the OP).

Comment: @David Faber just like you said, maybe he didn't noticed the last row that's why he assumed it'd be a basic group by, but thanks for commenting and thinking to fix my question, that is more than enough for me. thanks.

Comment: @DavidFaber, I had indeed not looked at the last row of the sample output. Apologies for the assumption. Seems like you got the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem. You can use [Tabibitosan](https://community.oracle.com/message/4473208) method for this. Refer the link for complete
explanation of this method.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9212a/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table hospi(
    patien_id   number,
    start_date  date,
    end_date    date,
    unit_name   varchar2(1),
    bed_number  number
);

insert into hospi values(1, date'2015-01-01', date'2015-01-02',  'A',  1);
insert into hospi values(1, date'2015-01-02', date'2015-01-03',  'A',  2);
insert into hospi values(1, date'2015-01-03', date'2015-01-03',  'B',  1);
insert into hospi values(1, date'2015-01-03', date'2015-01-04',  'C',  5);
insert into hospi values(1, date'2015-01-04', date'2015-01-06',  'C',  8);
insert into hospi values(1, date'2015-01-06', date'2015-01-07',  'C',  9);
insert into hospi values(1, date'2015-01-07', date'2015-01-08',  'A',  1);
insert into hospi values(2, date'2015-01-07', date'2015-01-08',  'A',  1);
insert into hospi values(2, date'2015-01-08', date'2015-01-08',  'B',  1);
insert into hospi values(2, date'2015-01-08', date'2015-01-09',  'B',  1);
```

**Query**:

```
select
    patien_id,
    min(start_date)     start_date,
    max(end_date)       end_date,
    unit_name
from (
    select 
        patien_id,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        unit_name,
        row_number() over (partition by patien_id order by start_date, end_date) -
        row_number() over (partition by patien_id, unit_name order by start_date, end_date)     grp
    from hospi
)
group by
    patien_id,
    unit_name,
    grp
order by
    patien_id,
    start_date,
    end_date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9212a/3/1)**:

```
| PATIEN_ID |                START_DATE |                  END_DATE | UNIT_NAME |
|-----------|---------------------------|---------------------------|-----------|
|         1 | January, 01 2015 00:00:00 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |         A |
|         1 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |         B |
|         1 | January, 03 2015 00:00:00 | January, 07 2015 00:00:00 |         C |
|         1 | January, 07 2015 00:00:00 | January, 08 2015 00:00:00 |         A |
|         2 | January, 07 2015 00:00:00 | January, 08 2015 00:00:00 |         A |
|         2 | January, 08 2015 00:00:00 | January, 09 2015 00:00:00 |         B |
```

Note: If you dont store the time part in start_date and end_date, and if there are many transfers between units on same day, You cannot determine the order
in which the transfer occurs.

Comment: thanks, it was perfect, we do have a date and a time but I didn't put the time because its the same logic and I didn't want to make my example a little bit complicated, regardless, you query and explanation was top notch, thanks again.